# Best report generation method for VB.NET in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I was using crystal reports with visual studio 2010, but it was really difficult in visual studio 2012. I am going to install 2013, what would be the methods other than crystal reports? Please mention if there are good resources to learn that.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic] page: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." Your question both asks for both a recommendation and an off-site resource.

Comment: The .NET Microsoft Reports (.rdlc definition) are really pretty good, have built-in support in VS and they are the equivalent of SSRS Reports. I personally wouldn't over look this option.

Comment: @KenWhite thank you for advice, i will never do that. thank you for the suggestion robnick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few...

1. Telerik
2. [Combit](http://www.combit.net/en/)
3. Component One

Each will vary in price as well. Crystal reports was easy for me, you just have to play around with it. Besides what issues were you having?

Comment: It was very hard to get working in visual studio 2012. I had to install various builds of crystal reports to choose correct one. I am afraid that same scenario will be there for the visual studio 2013.

Comment: All of them have their pros and cons, I personally have worked with them all besides combit and Ill tell you that each one was a learning experience and each one was a pain at times. Personally speaking Crystal Reports was the easiest to get going out of them all, that's all I was saying. Remember this, you asked the question, I gave my opinion. If you expect to not have issues, than what? Besides, figuring issues out is part of engineering, that's what we do best.

Comment: I commented because you have asked the issues? your opinion is welcomed.

Comment: Thank you, it really kind of depends on you really. Do you have the needed funds to get such software, if not Crystal Report would definetly be my option as the others cost. Besides of you have specific issues appropriate for SO someone can help you, that's what we do.

Comment: Yes me too. No I don't think of using paid software, I will try crystal reports but after the build I am not sure application will work on other computers, they probably require crystal reports run time environment etc.

Comment: When you compile it should include the needed dll's.